# Cómo validar una cadena de caracteres en C

Tags: c

Mi intención es hacer una especie de login, ¿cómo podría validar una cadena?, por ejemplo el nombre de usuario.

```
if(nombreUsuario == admin)
{

};
```

Comment: Hola Neifi, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `strcmp` contenida en `string.h`.

```
strcmp(Primera_Cadena, Segunda_Cadena)
```

- Si la primera cadena se igual a la segunda entonces
  retornara 0.
- Si la primera cadena es mayor que la segunda,
  retornara un valor superior a 0.
- Si la segunda cadena es mayor que la primera,
  retornara un valor inferior a 0.

```
if(strcmp("cadena", "cadena") == 0)
{
    puts("ambas cadenas son iguales");
}
```

Tambien debes saber que la funcion `strcmp` es sensible a mayusculas por lo que quizas quieras antes hacer uso de algotra funcion como `tolower` o `touper` y quieras convertir tu cadena a mayusculas o minusculas, dichas funciones aceptan un unico caracter.